# Style attribute attr/colorSecondary not found

Tags: android, styles

I can't build my project. It shows me `attr/colorSecondary` not found error.

These are my styles and manifest files:

> Android studio version: 3.0 canary 9
>
> compileSdkVersion 25
>
> buildToolsVersion '25.0.3'
>
> minSdkVersion 17

**Style**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryColor</item>
    <item name="colorSecondary">@color/secondaryColor</item>
</style>
```

**Colors**

```
 <color name="primaryColor">#fcc425</color>
 <color name="secondaryColor">#e5af17</color>
```

**Manifest**

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

**Dependency**

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
```

**Error Message**

> C:\Users\Raja.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-25.3.1.aar\9d599a32a67c8fb41b4e2d36c5f93152\res\values\values.xml
>
> Error:(353, 5) style attribute 'attr/colorSecondary (aka
>   com.equitasbank.merchant:attr/colorSecondary)' not found
>
> Error:D:\Android Projects\Purz Merchant\Equitas Merchant
>   Android\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeLiveDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:609
>   style attribute 'attr/colorSecondary (aka
>   com.equitasbank.merchant:attr/colorSecondary)' not found
>
> Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AaptException: AAPT2 link failed:
>
> Error:com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AaptException: AAPT2 link
>   failed:
>
> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processLiveDebugResources'.
>   Failed to execute aapt

**Console Error**

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processLiveDebugResources'.
> Failed to execute aapt

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:processLiveDebugResources'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:63)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:124)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:80)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:105)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:625)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:580)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
Caused by: org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Failed to execute aapt
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessAndroidResources.invokeAaptForSplit(ProcessAndroidResources.java:583)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessAndroidResources.doFullTaskAction(ProcessAndroidResources.java:281)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:106)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:173)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:134)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:121)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:122)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:111)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
```

Comment: Do you have color with that name in Res > Values > Colors.xml ?

Comment: Yes I have. Please check the edited question

Comment: i have added implementation "com.android.support:design:$android_support_version" this library and it`s working, in my case $android_support_version = 28.0.0-alpha3

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to explicitly define the 'attr' type in the item in AS 3.0

eg.

```
<item type="attr" name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryColor</item>
```

Docs: https://web.archive.org/web/20180518223123/https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration

Also, don't forget to define the attribute in your attrs.xml.
eg.

```
<declare-styleable name="Theme">
    <attr name="colorPrimary" format="color|reference" />
</declare-styleable>
```

Comment: The link you shared has nothing specific about the question

Comment: @GeekGuy They removed the migration guide.. if you look at the url, you just get redirected to the generic build page now. I updated with the link to the archive.org version of the same page.

Comment: What exact values go in they type tag? I'm still getting errors.

Comment: @TheRealChx101 you literally put "attr" as the type for the item element. That specifies to the compiler to look in the attrs.xml file for the attr element with the specified name

Answer (score 5):

The error you're getting is telling that the problem is that Theme named `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` doesn't contain attribute `secondaryColor`. So what you're basically trying to do is assign value to non-existent attribute.

Depending on your needs, you can choose from existing attributes (easiest way to get them is by pressing CTR + SPACE inside empty quotes in `item name = ""`) , or just add regular color and use it directly in the layout or Java code.

Answer (score 1):

Had the similar problem after I added a car lib.

```
AAPT: error: style attribute 'attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingleAnimated (aka ****debug:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingleAnimated)' not found.
```

That missing attribute was available in

```
implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.1.1'
```

Just check which lib the missing attribute is available in and add that as dep.