# Android Studio new project error on values

Tags: android, android-studio

When I create a new project he gives me all these errors on values file

> **Is any way to fix it?**

```
>/home/casimiro/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/support-compat-26.1.0.aar/b98e66e2aac1160aaf1abece79f4239c/res/values/values.xml
Error:(49, 5) error: style attribute 'attr/colorPrimary (aka com.casimiro.pap:attr/colorPrimary)' not found.
Error:(49, 5) error: style attribute 'attr/colorPrimaryDark (aka com.casimiro.pap:attr/colorPrimaryDark)' not found.
Error:(49, 5) error: style attribute 'attr/colorAccent (aka com.casimiro.pap:attr/colorAccent)' not found.
/home/casimiro/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/appcompat-v7-26.1.0.aar/7b14486d9f20631159bf075d741601e4/res/values-v14/values-v14.xml
Error:(8, 5) error: resource dimen/abc_text_size_button_material (aka com.casimiro.pap:dimen/abc_text_size_button_material) not found.
/home/casimiro/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/appcompat-v7-26.1.0.aar/7b14486d9f20631159bf075d741601e4/res/values-v21/values-v21.xml
Error:(49, 5) error: resource string/abc_font_family_title_material (aka com.casimiro.pap:string/abc_font_family_title_material) not found.
Error:(49, 5) error: resource dimen/abc_text_size_menu_header_material (aka com.casimiro.pap:dimen/abc_text_size_menu_header_material) not found.
/home/casimiro/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/appcompat-v7-26.1.0.aar/7b14486d9f20631159bf075d741601e4/res/values-v11/values-v11.xml
Error:(67, 5) error: resource style/Widget.AppCompat.ButtonBar.AlertDialog (aka com.casimiro.pap:style/Widget.AppCompat.ButtonBar.AlertDialog) not found.
Error:(67, 5) error: resource style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless (aka com.casimiro.pap:style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless) not found.
Error:(67, 5) error: resource bool/abc_config_closeDialogWhenTouchOutside (aka com.casimiro.pap:bool/abc_config_closeDialogWhenTouchOutside) not found.
Error:(72, 5) error: resource style/Widget.AppCompat.ButtonBar.AlertDialog (aka com.casimiro.pap:style/Widget.AppCompat.ButtonBar.AlertDialog) not found.
Error:(72, 5) error: resource style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless (aka com.casimiro.pap:style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless) not found.
```

> **Here is the style.xml**

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

In the style.xml gives me an error on the `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`

Comment: add code from `styles.xml` in question

Comment: @rupinderjeet done

Comment: Try "File > Invalidate Caches/Restart > Invalidate and Restart" option from menu bar.

Comment: @rupinderjeet I already have tried but with no success

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/a/46782327/3682535 If it fails, tell me how you created the project and your AndroidStudio version.

Comment: @rupinderjeet doesn't work

Comment: @rupinderjeet i'am using Android Studio v3.0.1