# @style attribute crashes on api 24 and lower

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a separate design library for shared UI components and styles.

```
<style name="Button.Secondary" parent="Button">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/secondary_button_state</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/blue</item>
</style>

<style name="Button.Secondary.Large" parent="Button.Secondary">
    <item name="android:drawableRight">@drawable/ic_chevron</item>
    <item name="android:drawableTint">?android:colorSecondary</item>
    <item name="android:paddingStart">8dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingEnd">8dp</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center|start</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/Subhead.Large</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-thin</item>
</style>
```

In my app I'm using a button style attribute from my design library.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/share_button"
    style="@style/Button.Secondary.Large"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Share Crew"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/crew_specialty_label" />
```

Api 25 and up this works fine with no issues. Api 24 and lower components using that style are unable to inflate.

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #100: Binary XML file line #100: Error inflating class Button
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #100: Error inflating class Button
    Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 79: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x1010530 a=3}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `<style name="Button.Secondary.Large" parent="Button.Secondary">`

- Add the following two lines to support older versions than API 17

  `<item name="android:paddingLeft">8dp</item>
  <item name="android:paddingRight">8dp</item>`
- DrawableTint

  `<item name="android:drawableTint">` is just used in API 23 and higher so be aware that it might not behave as expected in lower versions
- `?android:colorSecondary` Requires API 25 to work

  To fix you could just call your secondary color directly like `@color/colorSecondary`

Comment: Looks like ?android:colorSecondary was the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

Might be worth checking if *android:colorSecondary* is in earlier APIs:

[Style attribute attr/colorSecondary not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45635048)