# AppCompatActivity library not found with Sdk Version 28

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin

I'm creating a new android project with SDK 28 when project finished to create I have an error in MainActivity.

I tried some methods:

Clean project

Clean Android Studio cache

Clean Gradle cache

Re-installed IDE

File-> Invalidate cache/restart

Remove .idea folder

Restart Android Studio.

Android Studio About:

```
Android Studio 3.3.2
Build #AI-182.5107.16.33.5314842, built on February 15, 2019
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b01 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0
```

build.gradle (Module:app)

```java
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.israteneda.myapplicationtest2"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

MainActivity.java

```java
package com.israteneda.myapplicationtest2;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

The error showed is:

```
Android resource linking failed
error: resource style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar (aka com.israteneda.horariu:style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar) not found.
D:\israt\android_apps\HorariU\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:173: error: style attribute 'attr/colorPrimary (aka com.israteneda.horariu:attr/colorPrimary)' not found.
D:\israt\android_apps\HorariU\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:174: error: style attribute 'attr/colorPrimaryDark (aka com.israteneda.horariu:attr/colorPrimaryDark)' not found.
D:\israt\android_apps\HorariU\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:175: error: style attribute 'attr/colorAccent (aka com.israteneda.horariu:attr/colorAccent)' not found.
error: failed linking references.
```

When I change the SDK to 27 the MainActivity works.

build.gradle (Module:app)

```java
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.israteneda.horariu"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

MainActivity.java

```java
package com.israteneda.myapplicationtest2;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Also works with androidx library.

build.gradle (Module:app)

```java
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.israteneda.myapplicationtest"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0-alpha4'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0-alpha4'
}
```

MainACtivity.java

```java
package com.israteneda.myapplicationtest;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

I expect to create an android project without problems, but the actual output is an error with AppCompatActivity on MainActivity. Why does this problem happen?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Style attribute attr/colorSecondary not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45635048/style-attribute-attr-colorsecondary-not-found)

Comment: I follow the answer mentioned and change my style.xml but I get this error:

Android resource linking failed
D:\israt\android_apps\Test\app\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:11: error: resource style/AppTheme (aka com.israteneda.test:style/AppTheme) not found.
error: failed processing manifest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same issue and solved it by updating Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

1.Go to your project directory (or to Project View)

2.Find and open .idea directory

3.Remove caches and libraries directories

4.Invalidate Caches / Restart

Comment: I tried it but continuing to receive the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by updating the new version of android studio 3.4, without importing the settings of the previus version.